# Explanation of the last scene in Sense8 Season 2

Tags: plot-explanation, sense8

### Spoilers for Sense8 season 2 finale ahead

In the season 2 finale, Will (and part of the remaining gang) managed to get into BPO's facilities and rescue Wolfgang. From a dramatic perspective this seems to be surprising. However, the BPO is well guarded and if Will could have got into the interrogation room, there would be a big alarm or someone must have recognize him?

I am aware that the show has been canceled, but is there some in-show explanation or at least **some interview or statement from the show runners** which explains the overall plan for the last few minutes of the season?

Comment: Well Nomi Marks being a genius hacker she probably just shut down the security system so Will could enter easily.

Comment: Being downvoted for trying to answer, so I guess you won't have a proper answer as long as the directors won't clarify the ending.

Comment: so what exactly is your question? It's not really clear to me

Comment: I don't think it would have end up that way if they had known about the cancel